# jquery tab content works but tabheader doesn't, very rare bug

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-ui

I have a tab with 3 tabpages. I my second tabpage i have a button what makes a form in a modal-dialog. If I click on the submit button in my modal-dialog a row is added in the database and the modal-dialog will be closed. After this I use the OnSuccess method and it goes to a function that will show the third tabpage. This works! But the problem is is that it only show the content of that tabpage but the tabheader(better word?) is still on the second tabpage. I don't know how to fix this.

I use jquery-ui-1.10.3.

What i have tried:

Here i build my form and if it is valid the OnSuccess method gets called:

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "refreshAlerts()" }))
 { ... }
```

My HTML:

```
    <div id="tabs" class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active"><a href="#statistics" data-toggle="tab">Statistieken</a></li>
            <li><a href="#actions" data-toggle="tab">Alarmen</a></li>
            <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Instellingen</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

And here is the method where i have tried almost everything:

```
function refreshAlerts() {
    var tab = $('#tabs').tabs();
    jQuery("#tabs > ul").tabs({ active: null });
    jQuery("#tabs > ul").tabs({ selected: null });
    tab.tabs({ active: 2 });
    tab.tabs({ selected: 2 });
    tab.tabs('load', 2);
    tab.tabs('option', 'active', 2);
    tab.tabs('option', 'selected', 2);
    tab.tabs(2);
}
```

Only `tab.tabs('option', 'active', 2);` works. With this line of code it wil show the content from tabpage 3!

On the picture below I am on the second tabPage, the button opens a modal-dialog with a form.

---

[image]

---

If the form is submitted -> go to tabpage 3

---

[image]

---

Heee I see the content of tabpage 3 but the tabheader is still on tabpage 2. How can i fix this?

After submitting the form, my `ul` looks like this:

```
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" role="tablist">
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="statistics" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" aria-selected="false"><a href="#statistics" data-toggle="tab" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-1">Statistieken</a></li>
            <li class="active ui-state-default ui-corner-top" role="tab" tabindex="-1" aria-controls="actions" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" aria-selected="false"><a href="#actions" data-toggle="tab" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-2">Alarmen</a></li>
            <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active ui-state-active" role="tab" tabindex="0" aria-controls="settings" aria-labelledby="ui-id-3" aria-selected="true"><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab" class="ui-tabs-anchor" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" id="ui-id-3">Instellingen</a></li>
        </ul>
```

As you can see the second `li` has class 'active'.

Comment: Maybe because "2" means "third" element, since everything starts from "0". Have you tried "1" as parameter to open second tab?

Comment: I want to go to tabpage 3!! The content is right but the header is still on tabpage 2 and must go to tabpage 3

Comment: With `tab.tabs({ active: 2 });` it should work..check this..http://jsfiddle.net/4myDs/3/

Comment: Yes I know. I have that line of code in the `refreshAlerts()` function. But it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if something is wrong in your HTML, I tried with this example and it worked as intended...

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">1?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">2?</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">3?</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>this is 1</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>this is 2</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>3!!!!</p>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  var tab = $('#tabs').tabs();

  $("#tabs > ul").tabs({ active: null,selected: null });
  tab.tabs({ active: 2,selected: 2 });
  tab.tabs('load', 2);
  tab.tabs('option', 'active', 2);
  tab.tabs('option', 'selected', 2);
  tab.tabs(2);
</script>
```

Click to see [demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/pixshatterer/NLSmg/)

Comment: I tried it and it didn't work. I updated my question, now with my html code

Comment: @Jeffrey I just updated the fiddle with the code you posted and it is still working... gotta ask though, tabs were already there before form submission? after you submit, it refreshes the whole page or it is an ajax submission?

Comment: Yes and it is an Ajax submission

Comment: @Jeffrey can you create a simplified fiddle of what is happening to you? it is hard to guess w/out being able to reproduce the issue